# Error with no information when installing SQL SERVER 2012 on Vmware Virtual Server 2008R2

Tags: sql-server, virtual-machine, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a Virtual Windows Server 2008 R2 set up, I downloaded Sql Server 2012 Evaluation Copy. Now when I try to Install the Sql Server it throws an error, No Error message nothing at all just an error window pops up with no information at all.

Can anyone suggest me what is going on and how to fix this? thank you.

[image]

Comment: A random suggestion - try to run setup as admin. It has saved me and our nuclear power plant from many disaster.

Comment: Most llikely a damaged ISO file. Also check x86 vs x64.

Comment: Cheers guys for the suggestions, I am logged in as Administrator , and the same files were used to install on another physical machine without any issues.

Comment: Cheers @dean it was a damaged ISO file. Funny though since I have used the same file to install sql server before on another machine. You can post it as an answer and I will accept it as someone else can face the same issue and it can help others when diagnosing this issue Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely a damaged ISO file. Try downloading it again.