# SQL Server 2012 developer edition install error on windows 8.1

Tags: sql-server, windows

I am trying to install the iso version of SQL 2012 developer edition service pack 2 x64 on windows 8.1, when I click on setup.exe the command prompt comes up, disappears and a blank error box shows up with no message.

Comment: Experienced the same issue a couple of months back and it was actually bad .iso file. Did a lot of googling but no joy, and finally it turned out to be the bad iso file. Have a look here [`Error with no information when installing SQL SERVER 2012 on Vmware Virtual Server 2008R2`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23164506/error-with-no-information-when-installing-sql-server-2012-on-vmware-virtual-serv)

Comment: Have you checked the Windows event logs (Application, System)?

Comment: @hunch_hunch since the file never fires, there will be no error in windows event log.

Comment: @M.Ali you are correct, there is nothing in the windows event log. I downloaded the .iso from MSDN, is there somewhere else I can grab it from?

Comment: No just download it again and make sure download process is not disturbed while file is being downloaded, Also delete any existing SQL Server files. Just try to keep process as simple as possible.